# How execute directive logic after AngularJS template is evaluated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I have a pretty simple question (I don't know if the answer will be as simple) :
There is an `input` element :

```
<input type="text" datepicker  id="something-{{someValue}}" ng-model="someModel">
```

The `datepicker` directive consists in creating a jQueryUI datepicker linked to the `input` element.

The problem is : Datepicker doesn't work like that (it throws a "uncaught exception: Missing instance data for this datepicker" when I select a date). I think that the problem is that the datepicker needs an id to register but, when it registers, the id part isn't evaluated yet.

How can I execute the datepicker directive logic after the angular template is evaluated ?

Here is the directive code :

```
directives.directive('datepicker', [
            'Commons',
            function(Commons) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    require: 'ngModel',
                    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                        element.datepicker({
                            onSelect : function(dateText, obj) {
                                var modelPath = $(this).attr('ng-model');
                                Commons.putObject(modelPath, scope, dateText);
                                scope.$apply();
                            }
                        }).datepicker($.datepicker.regional['fr']).datepicker(
                                "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy").datepicker(
                                "option", "showAnim", 'clip');
                    }

                }
            } ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use $timeout

```
directives.directive('datepicker', ['$timeout',
        'Commons',
        function($timeout,Commons) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                $timeout(function() {
                element.datepicker({
                    onSelect : function(dateText, obj) {
                        var modelPath = $(this).attr('ng-model');
                        Commons.putObject(modelPath, scope, dateText);
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                }).datepicker($.datepicker.regional['fr']).datepicker(
                        "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy").datepicker(
                        "option", "showAnim", 'clip');
            })}};

        } ]);
```

use $timeout to queue your work to be run after current digest cycle (also waits for DOM rendering to be completed by the browser).